# Hide or ignore linter changes in PR

Tags: git, azure-devops, lint, pull-request

I am working on an Angular 4 (TS) project with a huge amount of legacy code in VS. I have an awesome automatic TS linter, but with the significant number of changes it makes to the file (e.g. adding space after closing paren, indenting, breaking up a line of code > 140 characters), my PRs have become very difficult to read when doing a side-by-side diff. (It doesn't help that most of the files are 1500+ lines.)

**My question:** Is there any way to reduce the number of linter changes visible in a PR (*but **not** the file itself -- we want to keep those updates*) to allow for better readability?

Obviously, I know Git can't "tell" whether a change is from a linter or was manually entered, but if I could set it to hide the addition of just new spaces and tabs, that would make a huge difference.

--

Note: We're using VSTS for version control. Might there be some sort of setting that I could change there instead?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not supported in VSTS pull request now, there is a user voice that you can vote: [pull request diff ignore whitespace](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/19544542-pull-request-diff-ignore-whitespace)